# Linux bash - break a files into 2-word terms

Tags: bash

I have put together this one-liner that prints all the words in a file on different lines:
sed -e 's/[^a-zA-Z]/\n/g' test_input | grep -v "^$"

If test_input contains "My bike is fast and clean", the one-liner's output will be:
My
bike
is
fast
and
clean

What I would need now is a different version that prints all the 2-word terms in the text, like this (still with the Bash):
My bike
bike is
is fast
fast and
and clean

Would you know how to do it?

Comment: Would

sed 's/([a-zA-Z]+[^a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z]+)[^a-zA-Z]+/$1\n/g'

do it? I have no linux at hand...

Comment: @chiccodoro: Changing yours to `sed -r ...` and the `$1` to `\1`, it prints two words per line, but it doesn't repeat the words.

Answer (score 1):

Pipe your word file to this script's standard input.

```
#! bash
last_word=""
while read word
do
  if [ $last_word != "" ] ; then
      echo $last_word $word
  fi
  last_word=$word
done
```

Answer (score 1):

This also works:

```
paste  <(head -n -1 test.dat) <(tail +2 test.dat)
```

Answer (score 1):

use awk for this, no need anything else

```
$ echo "My bike is fast and clean" | awk '{for(i=1;i<NF;i++){printf "%s %s\n",$i,$(i+1) } }'
My bike
bike is
is fast
fast and
and clean
```

Answer (score 0):

This probably requires GNU `sed` and there's probably a simpler way:

```
sed 's/[[:blank:]]*\<\(\w\+\)\>/\1 \1\n/g; s/[^ ]* \([^\n]*\)\n\([^ ]*\)/\1 \2\n/g; s/ \n//; s/\n[^ ]\+$//' inputfile
```

Answer (score 0):

to your command add:

```
| awk '(PREV!="") {printf "%s %s\n", PREV, $1} {PREV=$1}'
```